# Alert Box does not appear in xamarin Forms, DisplayAlert()

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display to alert box after tapping or click on the selected `ListView` box.  Currently the `selectedItem` is binding to `SelectedTicket`, which trigger an object call `SelectedTicket` within the ViewModel.  Once the `SelectedTicket` is triggered, it then executes a `popup.show()` method with the `DisplayAlert()` method.  The `DisplayAlert()` method get executes but does not display the AlertBox.

[image]

==============================================

////Xaml Page

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TicketList,Mode=OneWay}" RowHeight="130"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TicketListTileTemplate}"  BackgroundColor="#d9deeb"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicket, Mode=TwoWay}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
</ListView>
```

==================================================

////ViewModal

```
public object SelectedTicket
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedTicket;
    }
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _SelectedTicket, value))
        {
            if ((value != null) && (value is TicketListItem))
            {
                popup1.Show();
                SelectedTicket = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

======================================================

////Popup.cs

```
async public void Show()
{
    DisplayAlert("Alert", "Your have been alerted", "OK");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One of the most common reasons I don't see a DisplayAlert is because it is being called on a Page that isn't active on screen.

As a quick workaround/test you can do

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Your have been alerted", "OK");
```

If this works, my first assumption is confirmed.

I always try to keep my code behind clean, hence calling from the ViewModel is certainly a good approach. Normally your MVVM Library has some code to help with display alerts.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayAlert()` is only available to `Page` objects (such as `ContentPage` or `NavigationPage`) see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/#Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert_Method), your Popup.cs might not be a `Page` object. Also you are not awaiting `DisplayAlert` which you always want to do with async methods. Finally, your `Show()` method may not be running on the UI thread.

Instead of trying to show the alert from your ViewModel, why don't you try displaying the alert from the code-behind of your XAML page like this:

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TicketList,Mode=OneWay}" 
          RowHeight="130"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TicketListTileTemplate}" BackgroundColor="#d9deeb"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicket, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          ItemSelected="OnItemTapped"> <!-- Notice ItemTapped here will trigger when an item is tapped, imagine that -->
```

In Code-behind:

```
....

private TicketViewModel _viewModel = new TicketViewModel();

....

public async void OnItemTapped (object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e) { //Notice I added 'async' to the method here, that is so we can 'await' the DisplayAlert below (ALWAYS 'await' the DisplayAlert and ANY other async methods)
    TicketListItem item = (TicketListItem)o;

    if (item != null) {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Your have been alerted", "OK"); //Notice the 'await' here
        _viewModel.SelectedTicket = null;
    }
}
```